# Logic for Finding total salary of each employee in spark-Core

Tags: apache-spark, left-join, rdd

**employee.txt :**

```
100|Surender
101|Raja
```

**salary.txt :**

```
100|2016-JAN|15000
100|2016-FEB|15000
```

Hi

I am doing some basic hands-on in sparkcore using scala.

The requirement is to calculate the total salary for each employee. If a employee does NOT have matching record in salary file then display his salary as 0

I tried the below code. I was able to go upto Join, but i dont know how to read the None and Some and not able to proceed further

Could someone help me on reaching the expected output .

```
scala> val empRDD = sc.textFile("/user/cloudera/inputfiles/employee.txt")
scala> val salaryRDD = sc.textFile("/user/cloudera/inputfiles/salary.txt")
scala> val empMapRDD = empRDD.map( elem => elem.split("\\|"))
scala> val salaryMapRDD = salaryRDD.map(elem => elem.split("\\|"))
scala> val empKeyValueRDD = empMapRDD.map(elem => (elem(0),elem(1))
scala> val salaryKeyValueRDD = salaryMapRDD.map(elem => (elem(0),elem(2)))
scala> val joinedRDD = empKeyValueRDD.leftOuterJoin(salaryKeyValueRDD)
scala> joinedRDD.collect
res3: Array[(String, (String, Option[String]))] = Array((101,(Raja,None)), (100,(Surender,Some(15000))), (100,(Surender,Some(15000))))
```

**Expected Output :**

```
Array((100,Surender,30000), (101,Raja,0))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
val joinedRDD = empKeyValueRDD.leftOuterJoin(salaryKeyValueRDD)
  .groupBy(x => (x._1, x._2._1))
  .map(r => {
    val sal = r._2.map(x => x._2._2 match {
      case None => 0
      case Some(num) => num.toLong
    }).sum

    (r._1._1, r._1._2, sal)
  })

  println(joinedRDD.collect.toList)
  //List((100,Surender,30000), (101,Raja,0))
```

After `groupBy(x => (x._1, x._2._1))` the intermediate data will be something like this

```
List(
  ((100,Surender),CompactBuffer(
    (100,(Surender,Some(15000))), 
    (100,(Surender,Some(15000))))
  ), 
  ((101,Raja),CompactBuffer(
    (101,(Raja,None)))
  )
)
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried the below style of code and I got the result

```
 ...
 scala> joinedRDD.map( elem => ((elem._1, elem._2._1),elem._2._2 match { case Some(i) => i.toInt case None => 0 } ) ).reduceByKey((x,y) => x+y).map(elem => (elem._1._1,elem._1._2,elem._2)).collect
```

Output :

```
 Array[(String, String, Int)] = Array((100,Surender,30000), (101,Raja,0))
```

Please let me know if there are some other ways to achieve the same result